# Erro de autenticação no WSDL

Tags: web-service, soap, firewall

usando o [phptester](http://phptester.net/) para testar o seguinte código:

```
<?phptry {
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$wsdlUrl = 'http://ws.portaledu.com.br:8051/wsConsultaSQL/MEX?wsdl';
$soapClientOptions = array(
    "login"      => "XxXxXxXx", 
    "password"  => "XxXxXxXxX",
    "stream_context" => $context,
    "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);

echo $status =(string) simplexml_load_string($client->RealizarConsultaSQL(['codSentenca'=>'06','codColigada'=>$CODCOLIGADA,'codSistema'=>'S','parameters'=>'CODCOLIGADA='.$CODCOLIGADA.';IDPS='.$IDPS.';CPF='.$CPF.';DTNASCIMENTO='.$DTNASCIMENTO])->RealizarConsultaSQLResult)->Resultado->DESCRICAO;

}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

recebo o retorno:

> WARNING SoapClient::SoapClient(http://ws.portaledu.com.br:8051/wsConsultaSQL/MEX?wsdl): failed to open stream: Connection refused on line number 17

Porque será que não autentica, será que preciso liberar mais alguma porta além da 8051 para fazer requisições SOAP?

Answer (score 1):

Quando o conteudo está num endpoint de um ws, via php o mais coerente é fazer via CURL...

```
<?php
    $runfile = 'http://ws.portaledu.com.br:8051/wsConsultaSQL/MEX?wsdl';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $runfile);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $content = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch); 

    echo $content;
```

Comment: a dica foi muito boa, mas deixa eu completar a pergunta pra a gente marcar de vez essa resposta como solução,a posto que vai conseguir completar o raciocínio.

Comment: aquele seu echo parece um tanto estranho... vou copiar ele e tentar entender

Comment: Ele é um pouco confuso mesmo, no entanto, o objetivo é: enviar uma requisição `SOAP` para esse `wsdl` que já mencionei acima, e chamar a função `RealizarConsultaSQL()` e mostrar na tela o seu retorno!

Comment: sugiro resolver um problema por vez... dar um echo no retorno primeiro e qdo estiver retornando o que espera partir apenas para a função, ai fica mais organizado o raciocínio. Sobre exibir o maior, dependendo de como vier o retorno vc pode transformar em array e apenas eleger o maior da lista.

Comment: Estou entendendo, mas me ajuda a compreender aqui, porque esse código não me retornou erro, muito menos xml (não retornou nada), como irei fazer a requisição para o `RealizarConsultaSQL()`

Comment: na verdade o xml ta retornando ate qdo eu colo direto no navegador, entao pelo CURL tmb estará! a partir dai vc só precisa processar o retorno dela.

Comment: Tente entender este processo e como ele gera o seu código para consumir o serviço:
 https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-wsdl-creator/